# Countdown Timer in recyclerView always speeds up

Tags: android, timer, android-recyclerview, seekbar, countdowntimer

I have a Countdown Timer inside a custom recyclerView adapter. The timer runs a seekbar which displays progress over a minute. All the items in the recyclerView are suppose to display the same progress in the seekbar.
My problem is that the countdown timer always seems to accelerate after the seekbar reaches it's max progress the first time. How can I keep the countdown timer going the same speed?

**OnCreateViewHolder in my recyclerView adapter:**

```
  @Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {

     vi = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.businesslistitem, parent, false);

    final SeekBar seekbar = (SeekBar) vi.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

    //Use previous seekbar position
    if (POSITION != 0) {
        seekBar.setProgress(PROFITPOSITION);
    }

    //Disabling touch events
    seekBar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60000, 60) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
            seekBar.setProgress(profit_bar.getProgress() + 1);
            POSITION = seekBar.getProgress();

            //If the seekBar reaches it's max the CounDownTimer finishes
            if (seekBar.getProgress() == 1000) {
                onFinish();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            seekBar.setProgress(0);
            PROFITPOSITION = 0;
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            start();
        }
    }.start();

    return new ViewHolder(vi);

}
```

Comment: Does its speed increase or does the speed remain the same with a bit of jump at the start?

Comment: Try making the declaration of the countdown timer local

Comment: @RayHong The speed increases.